# Find All longest palindrome - getting only only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find all the possible longest palindromes derived a string?

what I am getting is only one:

```
herp = ""

def isPalindrome(s):
    if s == s[::-1] :
        return True

s = input()

for idy, item in enumerate(s):
    for idx, item in enumerate(s):
        derp = s[idy:idx+1]
        if isPalindrome(derp) and (len(derp) > len(herp)):
            herp = derp

print(herp)
```

for eg. string is `NITIN`

output : `INTNI
       NITIN`

Comment: _all longest_??

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ yes like what if there are two longest palindromes(both of longest length for eg. 5)

Comment: @YaShChaudhary you want to find 2 longest palindromes in one input? Please share and example input and output.

Comment: where does `INTNI` come from? It's not in the input string.

Comment: @Barmar its a palindrome derived from the string nitin

Comment: It's a permutation of the input string that's a palindrome, it's not in the original input string.

Comment: @Barmar yes it is

Comment: Where does the question say anything about permuting the input? And where are you calculating the permutations in your code?

Comment: This is homework for some course that expires shortly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385351/palindrome-sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the example: 'INTNI' is a permutation of 'NITIN' so you first have to get all permutations and then check which ones are palindromes.

So using your 'isPalindrome' function you could try with this:

```
from itertools import permutations
def getPalindromes(stringVar):
    result = set()
    perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(stringVar)]
    for perm in perms:
        if isPalindrome(perm):
           result.add(perm)
    return result
```

Comment: It's pretty clear this is untested, as it has an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: You are right sorry, actually I better use a set in order to avoid repetitions

Comment: Right, `result = set()` fits the bill much better.

Comment: geting empty set

Comment: @TemporalWolf then what site is for?

Comment: @YaShChaudhary Help after you've **tried**. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @TemporalWolf what else you need me to try?

Comment: @TemporalWolf `getPalindromes('NITIN')`returns `{'NITIN', 'INTNI'}`